# How to create geo index in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, 2dsphere

I try to create a 2dsphere index in my collection, when i create a user that i should has a 2dsphere index.

I take a reference from this answer [Create & Find GeoLocation in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199658/create-find-geolocation-in-mongoose)

I use the code is this in my case:

```
DriverSchema.index({ "geometry": "2dsphere"});
```

But when i create a user, i don't see any 2dsphere index.
[image]

I don't know which step was wrong, wish some one can tell me.

Here is my schema code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PointSchema = new Schema({
    type: { type: String, default: 'Point'},
    coordinates: { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere'}
});

const DriverSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    driving: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    geometry: PointSchema
});

DriverSchema.index({ "geometry": "2dsphere"});

const Driver = mongoose.model('driver', DriverSchema);

module.exports = Driver;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your schema as below:

```
coordinates: {
  type: [Number], // <lng, lat>
  index: { type: '2dsphere', sparse: false },
  required: true,
},
```

After this create a new record and check in `Robo 3T` like this:

```
db.hotspot.aggregate([{$indexStats: {}}]);
```

And then you will get this output:

```
{
    "name" : "location_2dsphere",
    "key" : {
        "coordinates" : "2dsphere"
    },
    "host" : "neel-Vostro-1450:27017",
    "accesses" : {
        "ops" : NumberLong(0),
        "since" : ISODate("2018-03-11T14:04:12.785Z")
    }
}
```